# How to add sum of NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

Trying to tally up a score every time a kill is made and 5 points are added for each, however, it never adds the values and is thus stuck at 5 points even after additional kills are made. The following is my array code.

```
        NSMutableArray * scoreTally = [NSMutableArray array];
        NSNumber *scoreValue = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:5];
        [scoreTally addObject:scoreValue];

        int sum=0;
        for(int x=0; x < [scoreTally count]; x++)
        {
            sum += [[scoreTally objectAtIndex:x] intValue];
        }

        NSLog(@"SUM %D",sum);

        score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %d",sum];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply remove this line from your Method and place it in `-viewDidLoad`.

```
NSMutableArray * scoreTally = [NSMutableArray array];
```

---

**Advice :** I noticed one thing in your code that you are using `for loop` to calculate the sum. There is one much better approach to calculate the sum of all the values inside an Array which is called [KVC](http://cupsofcocoa.com/2011/05/09/objective-c-lesson-13-key-value-coding/).

```
int sum = [scoreTally valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.self"];
```

The best part of KVC is that it is so simple and so easy to use and it reduces the number of lines code to a single line and hence the time.

Comment: nice and concise, +1 to you.

Comment: What is this magic "@sum.self"? Are there any more of these? Any documentation?

Comment: Or I could just google it myself! Here's some [documentation](http://cupsofcocoa.com/2011/05/09/objective-c-lesson-13-key-value-coding/)

Comment: @JamesWebster: Thanks. I am adding your Link to my Answer.

Comment: Key-Value Coding Programming Guide: Collection Operators: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html

Answer (score 1):

This is because you keep re-creating your "`scoreTally`" array so it's constantly being reset to an array with a single NSNumber object.

You need to create your "`scoreTally`" array ***once*** and then add additional objects to it as scores keep getting added.

So I'd recommend moving your "`scoreTally`" creation somewhere else, for example the "`viewDidLoad`" method of your view controller (making sure to keep "`scoreTally`" around via an ivar or a property).